# How can Add "Add To Cart" Button in single-product.php page

Tags: woocommerce

I want to add "Add to cart" Button in my custom single product page . Is there any shortcode or anything to show that button .

Answer (score 1):

try putting `do_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart' );`

Comment: Fatal error:  Call to a member function is_purchasable() on string in

Comment: that just mean your single-product.php is not woocommerce. what are you trying to achieve by the way?

Comment: Got the solution with this shortcode
do_shortcode('[add_to_cart id="'.get_the_ID().'"]');